# File permissions are not changing using the chmod command

Tags: command-line, chmod

I want to transfer files from my PC to an external HDD. I tried all the chmod commands but they are not changing file permissions. The GUI settings are also not working. My external HDD is NTFS.

Comment: Hey Are you trying to change the permissions for files you have copied from a Ubuntu system to an NTFS drive?

Comment: NTFS does not support UNIX style permissions so chmod wont work on NTFS partitons and their files.

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because you are trying to change permissions on a file system, ntfs, that does not support linux ownerships and permissions. Such file systems are mounted with default settings, which eventually can be adapted through the mount options.